# Is the latest version of xattr (0.6.4) compatible with the latest stable version of Python (2.7.5)?

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, xattr

I'm asking this question because I'm having problems installing Little Snitch 3.1 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3. Indeed, I'm getting the following error:

Error removing quarantine on ...: **python version 2.7.5 can't run `/usr/bin/xattr`**.  Try the alternative(s):

```
/usr/bin/xattr-2.5 (uses python 2.5)
/usr/bin/xattr-2.6 (uses python 2.6)
/usr/bin/xattr-2.7 (uses python 2.7)
```

Run `man python` for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.

Mountain Lion comes with Python 2.7.2. I updated Python to version 2.7.5 using the instructions found here:
http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx

Personally, I understand neither what the quarantine is nor what xattr does!

The help I got from Little Snitch Support was:
"Without MacPorts option to switch back to previous versions, it would be best for you to reinstall your 10.8.3 system files from the OS X Installer Disk to hopefully recover the python installation."

Yet, I followed Wolf Paulus' instructions because I wanted to avoid having several version of Python on my Mac. I just wanted the latest stable version, i.e. 2.7.5. I also suspect that doing what Little Snitch Support proposes is really going to make things messy on my Mac!

Any help in understanding the problem or, even better, solving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.